# Кнопка scroll to для любого разрешения экрана

Tags: javascript, html

Как сделать, чтобы вот такая scroll to кнопка приводила не к координатам, а к конкретному диву что-ли?

В общем нужно чтобы на любом экране она прокручивала до формы обратной связи

```
$(function() {
   $('.button').click(function() {
       $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:1000},800);
    });
 });
```

Дополнение: HTML код формы

```
<form id="send-form">
    <div class="form-group" style="text-align:left">
        <label for="input-name">name</label>
        <input type="name" class="form-control" id="input-name" placeholder="HOME COMPLETO" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" required>
        <small id="nameHelp" class="form-text text-muted">gfdgdf</small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="text-align:left">
        <label for="input-phone">phone:</label>
        <input type="phone" class="form-control" id="input-phone" value="+39" data-toggle="tooltip" title="+39 XXX XXX XX XX" required>
        <small id="phoneHelp" class="form-text text-muted">hgfhf</small>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: сделайте якорь и будет Вам счастье)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(function() {
   $('.button').click(function() {
       $.scrollTo("#formId", 800);
    });
 });
```

#formId - селектор вашей формы обратной связи

UPD:
не опознал что scrollTo работает через плагин https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo, вот в чистом jquery:

```
$(function() {
   $('.button').click(function() {
     $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#formId").offset().top
     }, 800);
   })
})
```

Comment: Почему-то не работает :( Селектор к <form> добавил, в функцию вписал. Нажимаю - ничего не происходит

Comment: @КириллМиронов добавьте в вопрос ещё html с формой, дело может быть в селекторе

Comment: @КириллМиронов прошу прощения, не опознал, что с плагином отправил) Обновленный вариант должен работать

Answer (score 1):

```
let coordY = document.querySelector(sel).getBoundingClientRect().y;
window.scrollBy(0, coordY);
```

так ты получишь точные координаты до нужного элемента в любой части страницы. А плавный скролл можно имитировать добавляя по 10/20 от текущей прокрутки к нужному элементу через setInterval.

либо:

```
    let coordY = document.querySelector(sel).getBoundingClientRect().y;
window.scrollBy({
    top: coordY,
    left: 0,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
```

но по поддержке смотри сам.

Comment: Тогда уж https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView использовать, и поддержка лучше, и опция для плавного скролла уже есть на большей части браузеров

Comment: Каким-то чудом я не знал про сий метод. Спасибо!!!